# How do I fix the ValueError?

Tags: python, valueerror

I used the Python for Kids book to learn the basics of Python 2.7.14, and there's this Python written game in it. It is a number guessing game, but in line 40 of the code, the ValueError keeps popping up. How do I fix this?

Line 40: `if comnum == int(players_guess):`

Whole code:

```
# New constants
QUIT = -1
quit_text = 'q'
quit_message = 'Thanks for playing'
comfirm_quit_message = 'Are you sure you want to quit (Y/N)?'

# New comfirm_quit funtion


def comfirm_quit():
    """Ask user to comfirm that they want to quit
    default to yes
    Return True (yes, quit) or False (no, don't quit) """
    spam = raw_input(comfirm_quit_message)
    if spam == 'n':
        return False
    else:
        return True


def do_guess_round():
    """Choose a random number, ask the user for a guess
    check wether the guess is true
    and repeat until the user is correct"""
    comnum = random.randint(1, 100)
    numofguess = 0
    while True:
        players_guess = raw_input('Input your choice:')
        # new if clause to test against quit
        if players_guess == quit_text:
            if comfirm_quit():
                QUIT
            else:
                continue  # that is, do next round of loop
        numofguess = numofguess + 1
        if comnum == int(players_guess):
            print('Correct!')
        elif comnum > int(players_guess):
            print('Too low')
        else:
            print('Too high')

    totalrounds = 0
    totalguesses = 0

    while True:
        totalrounds = totalrounds + 1
        print('Starting round number: ' + str(total_rounds))
        print('Let the guessing begin!!!')
        thisround = do_guess_round()

        # new if condition (and clode block) to test against quit
        if thisround == 0:
            totalrounds = totalrounds - 1
            avg = str(totalguesses / float(totalrounds))
            if totalrounds == 0:
                statsmsg = 'You completed no rounds. ' +\
                           'Please try again later.'
            else:
                statsmsg = 'You played ' + str(totalrounds) +\
                           ' rounds, with an averave of ' +\
                           str(avg)
            break

            totalguesses = totalguesses + thisround
            avg = str(totalguesses / float(totalrounds))
            print("You took " + str(thisround) + " guesses")
            print("Your guessing average = " + str(avg))
            print("")

        # Added exit messages
        print(statsmsg)
```

(I have changed the name of the variables in the code, so the variables won't be the same from the book.)

Error Message: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\26benk\Desktop\Programming\PY 2\Programs\Number_guess_game.py", line 40, in <module>
    if comnum == int(players_guess):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.1'`

Comment: What is the content of the `players_guess` variable? What is the set of input to the program?

Comment: What input you are passing?

Comment: Welcome! What's the full content of `players_guess` before you try to convert it to `int`?

Comment: Your indentation seems to be broken.  I assume your `while` loops are intended do be part of the preceding functions?  They aren't as posted.  You also forgot to include the exact text of the error, but given the line that you reference, it sounds like `int()` is probably failing to convert the string you're passing.  If that's the problem, then you either need to be careful not to input a non-number (other than the quit text), or else wrap it in a `try` to catch any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the type conversion in the line like this **if comnum == int(players_guess): to if comnum == players_guess:** and add these lines next to the raw input,

```
players_guess = raw_input(prompt)
try:
    players_guess = int(players_guess)
except ValueError:
    players_guess = str(players_guess)
```

This will definitely solve the case.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you dont have a break statement to pull you out of the loop where you are checking whether the user guesses the number correctly or not.

In this loop,

```
while True: 
    players_guess = raw_input(prompt)
    # new if clause to test against quit
    if players_guess == quit_text:
        if comfirm_quit():
            QUIT
        else:
            continue # that is, do next round of loop
    numofguess = numofguess+1
    if comnum == int(players_guess):
        print('Correct!')
    elif comnum > int(players_guess):
        print('Too low')
    else:
        print('Too high')
```

even if the user guesses correctly, he is asked for a `raw_input` because the loop is still active. If you hit enter, you will get the `ValueError` because you are trying the `int` function on an empty string. To avoid that, change your loop to

```
while True: 
    players_guess = raw_input(prompt)
    # new if clause to test against quit
    if players_guess == quit_text:
        if comfirm_quit():
            QUIT
        else:
            continue # that is, do next round of loop
    numofguess = numofguess+1
    if comnum == int(players_guess):
        print('Correct!')
        break
    elif comnum > int(players_guess):
        print('Too low')
    else:
        print('Too high')
```

There are other problems with this code as well. The first while loop has to be a function of the `do_guess_round` function